# ubuntu не видит реальное содержимое корневой папки

Tags: ubuntu, termux

Проблема появилась после установки gradle за этим гайдом `https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-1804/amp/`. Суть проблемы в том, что, единственные места в которые можно попасть это корневая папка (но ubuntu показывает не реальное ее содержимое). Вот что есть в корневой папке (по мнению ubuntu): `bin   etc   media  proc  sbin     sys   boot  home  mnt    root  srv      tmp  dev   lib   opt    run   var  usr.`

В папке `home` ничего. Там как минимум должна быть папка `storage`.

Comment: Фразы «...можно попасть это корневая папка» и «не видит реальное содержимое корневой папки» противоречат друг другу

Comment: Фраза "можно попасть это корневая папка..." не заканчиватся на слове "папка"

Comment: Это не отменяет того, что фразы всё равно противоречат друг другу, и в итоге вопрос даже ещё менее понятный, чем ваша предыдущая попытка задать его (и вообще под каждым вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1142288/edit), если что)

Comment: Я сомневаюсь что фразы "...можно попасть это корневая папка" и "не видит реальное содержимое корневой папки" протеворечат друг другу, т.к. в первой указывается "что возможно попасть только в корневую папку и её содержимое по (мнению ubuntu)" а во второй указывается что ubuntu видит не реальное ее содержимое.

Comment: В папках root и home что? И что значит - не реальное её содержимое? Что там должно быть, по вашему?

Comment: А что должно быть в корневой папке по вашему мнению?

Comment: Ubuntu - это дистрибутив, как он может что то показывать я затрудняюсь предположить. Покажите логи и от куда производится подлючение.